# Can't record browser clicks in JMeter for Chrome on Mac

Tags: macos, google-chrome, proxy, jmeter, opera

I tested with JMeter 2.5.1, 2.7, and 2.9
Chrome 29.1547.76, and 
FF 23.0.1
OSX 10.7.5

Is there a limitation with Chrome on Mac 10.7 and JMeter recording the test clicks for my test plan?  I have no problems using FF recording my few test clicks but Chrome does not record anything at all.  I'm visiting the same urls in both browsers and the Test Plan is the same in JMeter.

I followed the directions in http://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/jmeter_proxy_step_by_step.pdf.

A quick summary of what I did based on the tutorial above:

1. Create HTTP Request Defaults.  Server = jmeter.apache.org
2. Create Recording Controller
3. Add http proxy and included all patterns (regex = .*).  Did not exclude any patterns
4. Add Listener
5. Start the http proxy
6. Configure the browsers to use the proxy.

Configuring the browsers were slightly different.  Not sure if this was the cause.  Configuring FF, I went thru FireFox->Preferences->Network->Settings->Manual proxy configuration to change the proxy to my localhost and port 8080.  FF records my clicks.

Configuring Chrome, it seems to use the global Network settings and not have its own settings like FF does (System Preferences->Network->Advanced->Proxies->Web Proxy (HTTP).  Web Proxy server = localhost, port = 8080.  Chrome doesn't record my clicks.

I also stopped the proxy to see what happens when browsing.  FF does what I expected it to (gave a message saying proxy server is refusing connections and doesn't show me any pages I browse to).  Chrome doesn't do what I expect and allows me to visit all the pages I enter.

I don't have an issue using FF to create my test plan but I'm just curious (and OCD) as to why Chrome doesn't work for me and if anyone else ran into the same problem.  If someone knows the reason, please enlighten me.  Thanks in advance for your help.

EDIT:  I've also tried this with Safari and Opera and they also fail to get the test clicks recorded.  The only browser that works is FF, which doesn't go thru the System Preferences->Network->etc to setup the proxy.  FF has its own config for proxy setup  Screenshot of my System Preferences->Network screen is this:

[image: Mac proxy settings]

Screenshot of my JMeter proxy setup is this:
[image: JMeter proxy setup]

Also, I should have mentioned this earlier.  I think I saw it in the user manual.  When the proxy is stopped, FF doesn't allow me to access any web pages.  When the proxy is started, FF then allowed me to access pages and recorded my browsing click.  Chrome allowed me to access web pages, regardless of whether it was started or stopped, which should have been a sign it wasn't set up correct for whatever reason.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Proxy recording has been greatly improved in upcoming 2.10 version.

Can you give it a try using nightly build ? Ensure you use a JDK 7 when running JMeter :

- http://jmeter.apache.org/nightly.html

> Installing JMeter runtime
>
> Download the _bin and _lib files
>
> Unpack the archives into the same directory structure
>
> The other archives are not needed to run JMeter.

Also check that your system proxy setting do not exclude a localhost, see for example my Mac OSX config:

[image]

Finally ensure you didn't make any mistake if you configured URL patterns to include / Exclude, do a test without anything in these 2 fields to start with:

[image]

Edit:
it might also be due to domain restrictions from work.  After I rebooted the laptop, using the suggestions in this answer worked.  After waiting ~15 min, it stopped working.  There were other settings in System Preferences that I changed that got reverted to a default value after some time, which is why I think it's due to domain restrictions.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion.  The latest build (r1524817) didn't work for me.  Still had the same problem of Chrome not getting traffic captured but FF does get captured.  Thanks for the help though.

Comment: Thanks for continuing to think about my problem.  Yeah, I deleted what was there by default so i'm not bypassing localhost.  That box above is blank on my computer.  So, you don't have problems with the JMeter proxy server capturing your browsing session in Chrome?

Comment: Is there https in your site ?

Comment: No, no https on the site.  Like I said, it's so weird that FF browsing gets recorded but Chrome doesn't.  If no one else is having problems with recording browsing on Chrome, then I apologize for being an idiot and wasting people's time.

Comment: I updated answer. I made a test with Chrome 29.0.1547.76 and Mac OSX 10.6.8, I am not able to reproduce your issue

Comment: Note I did my tests with nightly build for now.

Comment: Thx for spending extra efforts looking at this with me. I included extra info in my post above too. I edited my JMeter proxy to not have anything in the include and exclude section but Chrome is still not being captured. I tried Opera and Safari too and they too didn't get my browsing captured. The only thing different between the browsers is FF has its own config for using proxies. The other 3 use the System Preferences to setup proxies. When I get home, I will try on my windows box too.  Thanks for going above and beyond. If I could give you extra upvotes for effort, I would. =)

Comment: PMD, thanks again for your help.  A possible cause might be company domain restrictions.  After rebooting my laptop and selecting the proxy in System Preferences, jmeter was able to record browsing activities from Chrome.  After waiting ~15 min, this didn't work again.

There were other settings (screensaver turn on after X min) I had changed but for some reason got changed back to some default setting so I assume there's some company domain restrictions that reset/change settings and this is affecting the proxy too.

Comment: you can edit my answer with this and accept it. Anyway why not record with firefox ?

Comment: yeah, i'm recording with FF.  I was just curious/confused why Chrome and the others didn't work.  I'm still not sure the cause but what I said above is my guess.  Thanks again for looking at this issue with me, even though it seemed like a simple, simple problem.